# Stackpanel with widthstyle set to fill?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I am in a situation where I want to add usercontrols in a panel. This has to be in a topdown order.

I have done whats explained [here](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2008/12/12/an-easy-stack-layout-panel-for-winforms/) to make it act like a stackpanel. However I want the width of each usercontrol to fill out the panel and not be a fixed size.

I tried using tablelayoutpanel and setting it grows attribute to 'add rows' but since I might be in a situation with more space the height is sometimes not constant because it wants to fill out the last row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the `TableLayoutPanel`.

To add controls, you can use the `TableLayoutPanel.Add(Control, int, int)` to specify the control, row, and column to put it in (in your case, column would always be 0). You can add rows by modifying the `TableLayoutPanel.RowCount` property. You would then set the `Control.Anchor` property on each control you add so it will stretch to the `TableLayoutPanel`'s width:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
tableLayoutPanel1.Add(b, 0, 0);
```

`AnchorStyles.Top` prevents it from stretching to the entire row's height.

This is just a rudimentary outline, but you should be able to work out how to make it work for you from this information, as well as the [MSDN page for TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx).